# Difference between VARCHAR2(10 CHAR) and NVARCHAR2(10)

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I've installed Oracle Database 10g Express Edition (Universal) with the default settings:

```
SELECT * FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS;
```

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8                                 
NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET         AL16UTF16
```

Given that both `CHAR` and `NCHAR` data types seem to accept multi-byte strings, what is the exact difference between these two column definitions?

```
VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)
NVARCHAR2(10)
```

Answer (score 91, accepted):

The [NVARCHAR2](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i45685) datatype was introduced by Oracle for databases that want to use Unicode for some columns while keeping another character set for the rest of the database (which uses VARCHAR2). The NVARCHAR2 is a Unicode-only datatype.

One reason you may want to use NVARCHAR2 might be that your DB uses a non-Unicode character set and you still want to be able to store Unicode data for some columns without changing the primary character set. Another reason might be that you want to use two Unicode character set (AL32UTF8 for data that comes mostly from western Europe, AL16UTF16 for data that comes mostly from Asia for example) because different character sets won't store the same data equally efficiently.

Both columns in your example (Unicode `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)` and `NVARCHAR2(10)`) would be able to store the same data, however the byte storage will be different. Some strings may be stored more efficiently in one or the other.

Note also that some features won't work with NVARCHAR2, see this SO question:

- [Oracle Text will not work with NVARCHAR2. What else might be unavailable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401043/oracle-text-will-not-work-with-nvarchar2-what-else-might-be-unavailable)

Answer (score 11):

I don't think answer from Vincent Malgrat is correct. When `NVARCHAR2` was **introduced** long time ago nobody was even talking about Unicode.

Initially Oracle provided `VARCHAR2` and `NVARCHAR2` to support localization. Common data (include PL/SQL) was hold in `VARCHAR2`, most likely `US7ASCII` these days. Then you could apply `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET` individually (e.g. `WE8ISO8859P1`) for each of your customer in any country without touching the common part of your application.

Nowadays character set `AL32UTF8` is the default which fully supports Unicode. In my opinion today there is no reason anymore to use `NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET`, i.e. `NVARCHAR2`, `NCHAR2`, `NCLOB`. Note, there are more and more Oracle native functions which do not support NVARCHAR2, so you should really avoid it. Maybe the only reason is when you have to support mainly Asian characters where `AL16UTF16` consumes less storage compared to `AL32UTF8`.

Comment: I easily assumed Unicode nature in `N...` types because I also work with SQL Server, which *apparently* (I'm not a guru in either DBMS) links VARCHAR/NVARCHAR to ANSI/Unicode Windows codepages, but of course Oracle is much older. In practice, perhaps `N...` can be left as potentially less obtrusive option for redistributable applications. Companies run really old legacy software in shared instances and it's less likely to get Unicode in VARCHAR2 than it is in NVARCHAR2.

Comment: You're right, when `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR2` were first introduced, they were not unicode-only. Still, it seems that these datatypes first appeared in Oracle 8 and the `UTF-8` character set was already supported.

Answer (score 7):

- The `NVARCHAR2` stores variable-length character data. When you
  create a table with the `NVARCHAR2` column, the maximum size is always
  in character length semantics, which is also the default and only
  length semantics for the `NVARCHAR2` data type.

  The `NVARCHAR2`data type uses `AL16UTF16`character set which encodes Unicode data in the `UTF-16` encoding. *The `AL16UTF16` use `2 bytes` to store a character*. In addition, the maximum byte length of an `NVARCHAR2` depends on the configured national character set.
- `VARCHAR2` The maximum size of `VARCHAR2` can be in either bytes or characters. Its column only can store characters in the default character
  set while the `NVARCHAR2` can store virtually any characters. A single character may require up to `4 bytes`.

By defining the field as:

- `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)` you tell Oracle it can use enough space to store 10
  characters, no matter how many bytes it takes to store each one. A single character may require up to `4 bytes`.
- `NVARCHAR2(10)`  you tell Oracle it can store 10 characters with `2 bytes` per character

**In Summary:**

- `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)`  can store maximum of `10 characters` and maximum of `40 bytes` (depends on the configured national character set).
- `NVARCHAR2(10)`  can store maximum of `10 characters` and maximum of `20 bytes` (depends on the configured national character set).

**Note:** Character set can be `UTF-8`, `UTF-16`,....

Please have a look at [this tutorial](http://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-nvarchar2/) for more detail.

Have a good day!

Comment: "The AL16UTF16 use 2 bytes to store a character". UTF-16 is variable-length and some characters require 4 bytes—does it mean that VARCHAR2 is fully Unicode compatible and NVARCHAR2 isn't? Or it's just an over-simplification?

Comment: Hi @ÁlvaroGonzález: We can say that VARCHAR2 is compatible with Unicode but support single character set while NVARCHAR2 support Unicode with multiple character set.
One reason you may want to use NVARCHAR2 might be that your DB uses a non-Unicode character set and you still want to be able to store Unicode data for some columns without changing the primary character set.

Comment: Another reason might be that you want to use two Unicode character set (AL32UTF8 for data that comes mostly from western Europe, AL16UTF16 for data that comes mostly from Asia for example) because different character sets won't store the same data equally efficiently.

Answer (score 3):

**nVarchar2** is a Unicode-*only* storage.

Though both data types are variable length String datatypes, you can notice the difference in how they store values. 
Each character is stored in bytes. As we know, not all languages have alphabets with same length, eg, English alphabet needs 1 byte per character, however, languages like Japanese or Chinese need more than 1 byte for storing a character.

When you specify **varchar2(10)**, you are telling the DB that only **10 bytes** of data will be stored. But, when you say **nVarchar2(10)**, it means **10 characters** will be stored. In this case, you don't have to worry about the number of bytes each character takes.

Comment: But I don't have `VARCHAR2(10)`, I have `VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)`, i.e., I'm not relying on the system's default semantics, I'm explicitly stating I want characters not bytes.

Comment: Yes, you are right! In that case, both would be able to store same length of characters.

Comment: Not fully correct. When you specify `varchar2(10)` then it could mean `varchar2(10 BYTE)` or `varchar2(10 CHAR)`. The default is defined by session parameter `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`. However, `NCHAR`, `NVARCHAR2`, `CLOB`, and `NCLOB` are always `CHAR`.