# What is the default value of VARCHAR2 in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, varchar2

I have a column in one of my tables that is of type `varchar2(2000)`, but does this mean `2000 bytes`? or `2000 characters`? Because I know there's a difference between bytes and characters...

Comment: See here also -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4508351/difference-between-varchar210-char-and-nvarchar210

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default is one of the `NLS` parameters of your session, namely `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS`.  Here is how I can check it from my session:

```
select value
from   v$nls_parameters
where  parameter = 'NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS'
;

VALUE 
------
BYTE
```

You can alter your session to change the value (or you can do it through the graphical interface in something like SQL Developer). You can also put an ALTER SESSION command in your `LOGIN.SQL` (or, globally, `GLOGIN.SQL`) if you use one, if you want a specific value to be assigned whenever you start a session. Otherwise, when you start a new session the default will come from your SPFile (most likely).

Here is how I can check what is in my SPFile:

```
select value
from   v$parameter
where  name = 'nls_length_semantics'
;


VALUE 
------
BYTE
```

I can also alter my system to change what's in the SPFile, but that's a DBA's job (I think). In any case, it CAN be changed.

This is similar to other `NLS` parameters - consider `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for example, the behavior is very similar.

Comment: Just to be sure... Does current session value affect the semantics of *existing* tables?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - no, it doesn't; and changing the DB parameter doesn't affect existing tables either. [From the docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS.html): "specifies the default length semantics to use for VARCHAR2 and CHAR table columns, user-defined object attributes, and PL/SQL variables in database objects **created in the session**"

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález - To understand Alex Poole's answer, you may want to consider this: When Oracle writes information to its dictionary tables (in this case, whatever is behind the `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` view), it always translates `varchar2` column width to BYTES. So if your current length semantics is `CHAR` and you create a column as `VARCHAR2(20)`, and your current character set is a four-byte character set (four bytes per character), then Oracle will simply store the fact that the column is 80 bytes wide. It will not remember that you declared it as 20 (CHAR, implicitly).

Comment: Thank you. That's what I had always taken for granted, but it was more an intuition than formal knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Further to @mathguy's answer, if you have an existing table you can query the data dictionary to see whether the size you're seeing (presumbaly via `describe` or similar) is in bytes or characters:

```
create table t (col1 varchar2(2000 byte), col2 varchar2(2000 char));

select column_name, data_type, data_length, char_length, char_used
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'T';

COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE DATA_LENGTH CHAR_LENGTH CHAR_USED
----------- --------- ----------- ----------- ---------
COL1        VARCHAR2         2000        2000 B
COL2        VARCHAR2         4000        2000 C
```

where `char_used` is C for a character limit and B for a byte limit.

The `data_length` is always in bytes, as that's the real upper limit, and is capped (to 4000 in my DB - could be 32k; in 12c+ with `MAX_STRING_SIZE` set to `EXTENDED`) - so even though I've said 2000 characters are allowed in `col2`, if I use multibyte characters then I may actually be allowed fewer than 2000 of those, as the total number of bytes could attempt to exceed 4000. I would actually see 4000 as the data length for anything declared larger than `999 char`, as it allows up to four bytes per character, for AL32UTF8.

The `describe` command in SQL*Plus etc. shows you the original size, and also shows you whether it is bytes or characters - but it omits that if it matches your session's `NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS` setting:

```
alter session set nls_length_semantics = 'BYTE';

desc t;

Name Null? Type                
---- ----- ------------------- 
COL1       VARCHAR2(2000)      
COL2       VARCHAR2(2000 CHAR) 

alter session set nls_length_semantics = 'CHAR';

desc t;

Name Null? Type                
---- ----- ------------------- 
COL1       VARCHAR2(2000 BYTE) 
COL2       VARCHAR2(2000)
```

That setting is also used for the default semantics if you don't specify `char` or `byte` in the create statement, also as @mathguy explained; but as with most NLS settings it's usually better (IMO) to explicitly state it so there is no ambiguity or confusion about what will happen.