# extract Oracle SQL Descr/Describe/Desc as an output table or excel file

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have 70+ tables with each having 30+ fields. 
I was asked to find data type and data length for certain fields in these tables, I thought it would be helpful to have an output file and then just search through it but I am not sure how do I get descr to accept multiple tables and give me an output?

```sql
descr table_name;
```

I have tried

```
Select table_name, column_name, data_type
From all_tab_columns
where table_name in (NAME OF MY TABLES)
```

This works but for some reason, the output is a little off in terms of data_length and I need data length as it shows on when executing Descr.

Edit:  I am working in SQL developer.

by off I mean in descr I get the outputs for A as datatype NUMBER(38) but in all_tab_columns it gives me data length 22

Comment: Please specify your database becuase every system handles things different.Fro mysql works 

SELECT COLUMN_NAME, TABLE_NAME,table_schema
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS;

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "off in terms of data_length". The information in all_tab_columns should be 100% identical to that returned by `DESCR`. Do you have an example where they don't match?

Comment: reading an output file would be easier/faster than just querying dba_tab_cols? if you want a report, SQL Developer has data dictionary reports/html schema docs that will give you what you're looking for

Comment: [Related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581465/266304); you could look at [other columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57578654/266304) to recreate what `describe` shows for char/byte?

Comment: I am using SQL developer from Oracle. and by off I mean in descr I get the outputs for A as datatype NUMBER(38) but in all_tab_columns it gives me data length 22

Comment: @Qasim - that is handled in the answer I linked to in my previous comment...

Comment: yes @AlexPoole thanks! I went over it the only trouble I now have is when I run descr it's giving me NUMBER(38) but the result using all_tab_columns gives me NUMBER(22)

Comment: That sounds like you are still using `data_length`, not `data_precision` (and `data_scale`)? Justin's answer also covers that distinction. (And my old answer shows a `NUMBER(38)` being reported properly.)

Comment: If you have data type `NUMBER` and both scale and precision are null then it is unconstrained; but then `desc` shows it as `NUMBER` and not `NUMBER(38)` ?

Comment: thanks, @alex very helpful of you, appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

If the precision and scale are both null then `describe` shows that column as a plain `NUMBER`, not as `NUMBER(38)`. If `describe` shows the column as `NUMBER(38)` then the data dictionary shows it with precision 38 and scale 0. Unless, that is, you created it as `NUMBER(*,0)`:

```
create table t42 (
  num number,
  num38 number(38),
  num5_2 number(5,2),
  num_3 number(*,3),
  num_0 number(*,0)
);

desc t42;

Name   Null? Type         
------ ----- ------------ 
NUM          NUMBER       
NUM38        NUMBER(38)   
NUM5_2       NUMBER(5,2)  
NUM_3        NUMBER(38,3) 
NUM_0        NUMBER(38)   

select column_name, data_length, data_precision, data_scale
from user_tab_columns
where table_name = 'T42';

COLUMN_NAME     DATA_LENGTH DATA_PRECISION DATA_SCALE
--------------- ----------- -------------- ----------
NUM                      22                          
NUM38                    22             38          0
NUM5_2                   22              5          2
NUM_3                    22                         3
NUM_0                    22                         0
```

For my `NUM_0` column `data_precision` is null, but `data_scale` is not, so - as with `NUM_3` - the precision is defaulted to the maximum of 38 when it is described.

Comment: Amazing!! thank you so much for this well-put explanation! :) it helped.

Comment: @Qasim - I've also updated the [answer I linked to before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581465/266304) to show those number variations; and also to handle character semantics better.

Comment: Brilliant!! Cheers @Alex

Answer (score 1):

Can you define what is "off" in `data_length`?  I assume that the issue is that for character columns you want the length in characters not bytes.  If so, you'd want the `char_length` column instead.  That's defined in terms of characters.  `data_length` is defined in terms of bytes.

Based on the edit, your problem appears to be with numeric columns.  You'd want the `data_scale` and the `data_precision` to tell you that a column was a `number(38,0)`.  `data_length` is the size of the column in bytes but you specify the precision of a number in terms of decimal digits so the two lengths should be different.

Comment: by off I mean in descr I get the outputs for A as datatype NUMBER(38) but in all_tab_columns it gives me data length 22. char_length gives me 0

Comment: @Qasim - Updated.  You want `data_scale` and `data_precision`.

Comment: thank you for the help I am still having issues with my Descr giving me Number(38) whereas all_tab_colum gives me 22

 data_scale and data_precision results are empty.

Comment: @Qasim - A value of 22 is almost certainly coming from `data_length` not `data_scale`.  It's helpful if you edit your question to include a reproducible script (i.e. a `create table` statement and then a query against `all_tab_columns` that shows the issue you're seeing that we can run on our local machine.  Or a link to a liveSQL.oracle.com session that demonstrates the issue you're seeing).

Comment: yes, you are right! :)  I got it working thank you for your kind help.