# How to store Â® in oracle table?

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, special-characters

I need to insert value into an Oracle table
'`RRÂ® 5`'?

I created a table column `varchar2` data type. 
But when I am displaying the data it is showing:
'`RR?? 5`'

Any idea, please.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28298/ch2charset.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [Defining a Character Set for a column For oracle database tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9956433/defining-a-character-set-for-a-column-for-oracle-database-tables)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is `RRÂ® 5` the _real_ value, or are you faking the data as that column was defined with a "wrong" encoding ? This look so much like [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) ...

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to check if your database runs on character encoding which supports your special characters.

Execute this query to check.

```
SELECT * 
FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS 
WHERE PARAMETER IN ('NLS_CHARACTERSET', 'NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET');
```

Character sets like `AL32UTF8`, `UTF8`, `WE8ISO8859P1` are able to store special characters `Â®`.
In order to check whether your characters are supported you can run this command

```
SELECT 
    ASCIISTR(CAST(UNISTR('\00C2') AS VARCHAR2(4))) AS VARCHAR_SUPPORT, 
    ASCIISTR(CAST(UNISTR('\00C2') AS NVARCHAR2(4))) AS NVARCHAR_SUPPORT
FROM dual;


VARCHAR_SUPPORT   NVARCHAR_SUPPORT                        
----------------  ------------------------
\00C2             \00C2                                   

1 row selected.
```

If your result value (`00C2`) is equal to your input value then your characters are supported.

Suppose your database supports the characters (otherwise the game ends here)

**Solution 1**

Run this command from any SQL editor or from SQL*plus

```
INSERT INTO THE_TABLE VALUES (UNISTR('RR\00C2\00AE 5'));
```

Depending on your actual requirements this can be a very tedious work.

**Solution 2**

Use SQL*plus command. For this you have to set `NLS_LANG` environment variable according to code page of `cmd`

```
C:\>chcp
Active code page: 850

C:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8PC850

C:\>sqlplus user/pwd@DB

SQL> INSERT INTO THE_TABLE VALUES ('Â®');
```

When you work on Linux/Unix the `chcp` equivalent is `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG`. You can also change current code page, e.g. `chcp 65001` for UTF-8

**Solution 3a**

Create a SQL script containing the same INSERT command as above, and save it with local encoding (typically `Windows CP1252`, many times misnamed as `ANSI`)

```
c:\>set NLS_LANG=.WE8MSWIN1252

c:\>sqlplus user/pwd@DB @Special_Char_CP1252.sql
```

**Solution 3b**

Create a SQL script and save it with UTF-8 which is supported by most modern editors. Note: SQL scripts **must not contain a BOM** (Byte Order Mark), otherwise SQL*plus will raise an error. I found this tiny command line tool to add and remove BOM from arbitary text files: [UTF BOM Utils](https://code.google.com/p/utf-bom-utils/)

```
c:\>set NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8

c:\>sqlplus user/pwd@DB @Special_Char_UTF8.sql
```

Note for solutions above: you can skip the `set NLS_LANG` command in case your registry is set accordingly. Check with this command

```
C:\>REM for x64 Oracle Client

c:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\ /s /v NLS_LANG

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
    NLS_LANG    REG_SZ    AMERICAN_SWITZERLAND.AL32UTF8

End of search: 1 match(es) found.    

C:\>REM for x86 Oracle Client

c:\>reg query HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\ /s /v NLS_LANG

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\ORACLE\KEY_OraClient11g_home1
    NLS_LANG    REG_SZ    AMERICAN_SWITZERLAND.AL32UTF8

End of search: 1 match(es) found.

C:\>
```

**Solution 4**

Run your INSERT statements from a more sophisticated editor like TOAD or SQL Developer. Ensure that NLS_LANG value in Registry, resp. your system environment variable matches the file save options of the editor.

Some external resources which may help you:

- Oracle documentation [NLS_LANG Settings in MS-DOS Mode and Batch Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/install.102/b14312/gblsupp.htm#i634455)
- List of Code pages: [Code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)
- Find a Unicode Codepoint: [Codepoints](http://codepoints.net/?lang=en)