# SQL Server TO Oracle table creation

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, oracle11g, annotations

We are using MS-SQL and Oracle as our database.

We have used hibernate annotations to create tables, in the annotation class file we have declared column definition as

```
@Column(name="UCAALSNO",nullable=false,columnDefinition="nvarchar(20)")
```

and this works fine for MS-SQL.

But when it comes to Oracle `nvarchar` throws an exception as oracle supports only `nvarchar2`.

How to create annotation file to support datatype `nvarchar` for both the databases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use NCHAR:

In [MSSQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx):

> nchar [ ( n ) ]
>
> Fixed-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and must
>   be a value from 1 through 4,000. The storage size is two times n
>   bytes. When the collation code page uses double-byte characters, the
>   storage size is still n bytes. Depending on the string, the storage
>   size of n bytes can be less than the value specified for n. The ISO
>   synonyms for nchar are national char and national character.

while in [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i3253):

> NCHAR
>
> The maximum length of an NCHAR column is 2000 bytes. It can hold up to
>   2000 characters. The actual data is subject to the maximum byte limit
>   of 2000. The two size constraints must be satisfied simultaneously at
>   run time.

Nchar occupies a fixed space, so for very large table there will be a considerable space difference between an nchar and an nvarchar, so you should take this into consideration.

I usually have incremental DB schema migration scripts for my production DBs and I only rely on Hibernate DDL generation for my integration testing in-memory databases (e.g. HSQLDB or H2). This way I choose the production schema types first and the "columnDefinition" only applies to the testing schema, so there is no conflict.

You might want to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4401043/oracle-text-will-not-work-with-nvarchar2-what-else-might-be-unavailable) too, which disregards the N(VAR)CHAR(2) additional complexity, so you might consider setting a default character encoding:

> Given that, I'd much rather go with the approach that maximizes
>   flexibility going forward, and that's converting the entire database
>   to Unicode (AL32UTF8 presumably) and just using that.

Although that you might be recommanded to use VARCHAR2, VARCHAR [has been synonym](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/1301/what-is-the-difference-between-oracles-varchar-and-varchar2-datatypes) with VARCAHR2 for a long time now.

So quoting a DBA opinion:

> The Oracle 9.2 and 8.1.7 documentation say essentially the same thing,
>   so even though Oracle continually discourages the use of VARCHAR, so
>   far they haven't done anything to change it's parity with VARCHAR2.

I'd say give it a try for VARCHAR too, as it's supported on most DBs.